# META catalogue: 'None of the products provided could be sent. Please check your catalog.' when sending with Whatsapp cloud api

Tags: facebook-graph-api, whatsapp, whatsapi

We have setup a catalogue on the meta business platform and it is connected to a whatsap business API account. The catalogue is setup to pull a `.csv` file from our server, this happens fine and uploads the products correctly.

The problem is that when we try to send a message with the whatsapp cloud API it acts like there are no products with those id's

This is the url `https://graph.facebook.com/v16.0/<phoneid>/messages` we query and this is the request body

```json
{
    "messaging_product": "whatsapp",
    "recipient_type": "individual",
    "to": "<mynumber>",
    "type": "interactive",
    "interactive": {
        "type": "product_list",
        "header": {
            "type": "TEXT",
            "text": "Tester"
        },
        "body": {
            "text": "test catagloue"
        },
        "action": {
            "catalog_id": "739765567592966",
            "sections": [
                {
                    "title": "Category 1",
                    "product_items": [
                        {
                            "product_retailer_id": "8275a-mwnje--"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "title": "Category 2",
                    "product_items": [
                        {
                            "product_retailer_id": "puy84-bnlzx--"
                        },
                        {
                            "product_retailer_id": "1mdqj-d0xyl--"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

This is the response we get:

```json
{"error":{"message":"(#131009) Parameter value is not valid","type":"OAuthException","code":131009,"error_data":{"messaging_product":"whatsapp","details":"None of the products provided could be sent. Please check your catalog."},"fbtrace_id":"AVOhyUrgCCiy-6xbYFCVzX7"}}
```

This tell me that everything else should be correct like token, numberid catalogueid, etc..

Here you can see the Content ID's of the uploaded products to make sure they match:
[Content ID's](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ph4KE.png)

The catalogue type is: Local commerce and delivery -> Menu and store items.

We did get this to work and send us the catalogue items with the E-commerce type catalogue

So as a last resort we could switch to that and see if that would solve our issue.

We tried different schedules for the upload, fixed and random content ID's, also tried turning off the upload schedule to see if it needed some time but nothing seemed to work.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that it takes a few minutes to an hour after you have added your Data source to be able to send your catalog products via whatsapp API.

Ensure you have done the following steps:

## Creating Commerce Catalogue

- Visit [Meta Commerce](https://business.facebook.com/commerce/)
- Fill in all details (Select Online Products)
- Get Catalog ID in Settings > Catalog
- Add data sources
- Link your catalog to your number, [WA Manager](https://business.facebook.com/wa/manage/catalog-linking) >
  Account tools > Catalog & Connect
- Assign the API user to the catalog [Business Settings](https://business.facebook.com/settings/product-catalogs) >
  Data Sources > Catalogs > People > Assign People (Probably not
  required)